# Scope of recursively called function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion

Does recursively called nested function have access to variables of the function where it is called in Matlab?

For example, in

```
function myfun
   % lots of code, including a base case somewhere
   %% an if/switch/try-catch block
   var=1;
   myfun;
   %%
end
```

suppose the nested `myfun` is called; does that nested copy have access to `var` from the get go?

Along the same line, when it comes to the line `var=1;` in the nested `myfun`, will a different `var` be created or will the `var` be modified in-place? Would it make a difference when the whole `myfun` is nested under another function where `var` is defined?

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning some context for your question. What is the desired behavior in your use case?

Comment: @Dev-iL Two things. 1) Matlab has been crashing on me recently. I can't tell why Matlab crashes since any error or warning messages would be gone.  The only suspect is that I have a recursively called function that checks the state of something else. So I want to understand the behaviors of Matlab's nested functions better. 2) Once I understand the scoping rules better, I can manually delete variables that are no longer needed when making recursive calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) recursively doesn't change any of the [normal scoping behavior](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html#f4-73993) that applies in cases of nested functions: any variables declared or used *only* in the nested function are local to that function, regardless of which recursive instance it is. Take this sample code:

```
function outer_fcn
  inner_fcn(0)
  function inner_fcn(n)
    count = n+1;
    fprintf('function %i entered\n', count);
    if (count < 3)
      inner_fcn(count);
    end
    fprintf('function %i exited\n', count);
  end
end
```

This will produce the following output:

```
>> outer_fcn
function 1 entered
function 2 entered
function 3 entered
function 3 exited
function 2 exited
function 1 exited
```

Each call of the function `inner_fcn`, regardless of whether it was made recursively, has it's own unique `count` variable in its scope. They aren't shared across calls. Now in the first line of `outer_fcn` replace `inner_fcn(0)` with `count = 0; inner_fcn(count);` and see what happens:

```
>> outer_fcn
function 1 entered
function 2 entered
function 3 entered
function 3 exited
function 3 exited
function 3 exited
```

Oops! Now that `count` exists in the outer scope, it gets shared as a single variable across all calls of the nested function, so it gets overwritten each time `inner_fcn` is called. This is the expected behavior, regardless of calling the nested function recursively.

Answer (score 0):

if you consult:
https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts-and-functions.html

explains that the variables are local to the function.

Therefore it is understood that a new variable is created for each call.

Example:

```
function y=myfun(var)
y= (var + 1);
   if y~=3
   myfun(var);
   end

end
```

Execute:

```
myfun(1)
```

Out Error:

```
Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program.

Error in myfun (line 4)
   myfun(var);
```

that implies that `y` is local to each function because it never reaches the value 3 and therefore it gives error.
Even if the function is called from a function, in response to your question!.

Comment: I can't tell if the error is only because y is simultaneously a local output and a variable to be modified by a nested function. Local output in recursive functions is treated differently by Matlab. Also see mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.htm